# Python / Django Forms - Display Form Element Content Instead of Html Element

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am looping through some forms and I want to display some of the values of certain form elements.  I have read that .data should take care of this for me.  However, that returns "None" and the form does indeed have the field and correct stored value...

```
{% for document in documents: %}
    {{ document.title.data }} <!-- NOTE:  This returns "None" -->
    {{ document.title }} <!-- Element with correct initial value -->
```

Any ideas?

Merci Beaucoup!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

1. To access an initial value directly `forms.CharField(initial=X`)
   Use `{{ document.title.field.initial }}`.
2. Accessing an initial value passed into the form constructor (`form = MyForm(initial={...})`) doesn't look possible via the template. `BoundField` does `data = self.form.initial.get(self.name, self.field.initial)` when rendering a widget to get at the form `initial` dict, then falls back to the form field's initial value.
3. For a bound form where you've passed in data, such as `form = MyForm(request.POST)`, 
   that data would be available in 
   `{{ document.title.data }}`

In trunk, `BoundField.value` returns either the initial or data! Cool stuff.
http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py#L438

Comment: Thanks Yuji. This seems a bit non-practical.  Is there a way to just access the value regardless of how it was given to the form object?  The reason this would be useful is because the same form template could be used without any logic to determine a submit or not...  Also, i just tried document.title.field.initial and it returns "None" even though my form does have the correct initial values...

Comment: I don't think so. I don't see anything in BoundField that might help. The forms widget rendering function themselves check if the form is bound to determine whether to (attempt) returning data from initial values or submitted values.

Comment: Any guess as to why I get "None" back when attempting the {{ document.title.field.initial }} method???  I am using an unsubmitted form and initial values are set just like your example. ???

Comment: Ew, my answer is wrong.  `boundfield.field.initial` is the specific field's initial value only (the `initial` passed into the field constructor). Getting the field passed into the form constructor's `initial` argument is dirty: `boundfield.form.initial.get(boundfield.name)`, which you can't do in template syntax. I'm stumped!

Comment: Ok.  I think this option should be available in django...  Anyhow, the solution i've been using is to build a tuple (document_object, form_object) inside an array called documents.  Then when I loop through the documents I use something like: "for document, form in documents" ...  then I can call "document.title" or "form.title" (for the form element...  If that makes any sense. Lol.  Once again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah! It would be an easy patch to separate the 3 line logic pulling out initial values in `as_widget` to make that initial value available!

Comment: PS: I noticed in trunk it HAS been implemented in `BoundField.value` http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/forms.py#L438